I'd like this script to work with "files and folders" and avoid the popup window
//  SendToQuickLaunch.js - Version 1.3
//  Copyright (c) 2010, 2013 Bill Chatfield <bill_chatfield@yahoo.com>
//  All rights reserved.

var programDesc = "Send to Quick Launch";
var quickLaunchMenuItem = "Quick Launch (create shortcut)";
var installFolder = getEnvironmentVariable("AppData") + "\\" + programDesc;
var installedScript = installFolder + "\\" + WScript.ScriptName;

var shell = null;
var environment = null;
var fileSystem = null;

/* Returns a FileSystemObject object */
function getFileSystem() {
    if (fileSystem == null) {
        fileSystem = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    }
    return fileSystem;
}

/* Returns a WshShell object */
function getShell() {
    if (shell == null) {
        shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    }
    return shell;
}

/* Returns a WshEnvironment object */
function getEnvironment() {
    if (environment == null) {
        environment = getShell().Environment("Process");
    }
    return environment;
}

/* Returns a String object */
function getEnvironmentVariable(name) {
    var env = getEnvironment();
    return env(name);
}

/* String */
function askOperation() {
    // Ask the user if they want to install.
    var answer = getShell().Popup("Install \"Quick Launch\" option in the \"Send To\" menu?", 300, programDesc + " - Admin", 4 + 32);
    if (answer == 6) { // If Yes
        return 'install';
    }
    var answer = getShell().Popup("Remove \"Quick Launch\" option from the \"Send To\" menu?", 300, programDesc + " - Admin", 4 + 32);
    if (answer == 6) { // If Yes
        return 'remove';
    }
    return '';
}

/* void */
function install() {
    // Copy this script into its formal install folder.
    if (! getFileSystem().FolderExists(installFolder)) {
        getFileSystem().CreateFolder(installFolder);
    }
    // Destination folder must end in a backslash to be recognized as a folder.
    getFileSystem().CopyFile(WScript.ScriptFullName, installFolder + "\\", true);

    // Create the link in the SendTo folder that is invoked by the
    // "Quick Launch" menu item on the "Send To" menu. This also
    // creates the menu item beause Windows creates the "Send To"
    // menu from whatever is in the "SendTo" special folder.
    var sendToFolder = getShell().SpecialFolders("SendTo");
    var link = getShell().CreateShortcut(sendToFolder + "\\" + quickLaunchMenuItem + ".lnk");
    link.TargetPath = installedScript;
    link.WindowStyle = 1;
    link.IconLocation = "wscript.exe, 3"; // The yellow JavaScript icon is at index 3.
    link.Description = programDesc;
    link.WorkingDirectory = installFolder;
    link.Save();

    // Create a link in the Start Menu to allow uinstalling of this script.
    var programsFolder = getShell().SpecialFolders("Programs");
    var startMenuFolder = programsFolder + "\\" + programDesc;
    if (! getFileSystem().FolderExists(startMenuFolder)) {
        getFileSystem().CreateFolder(startMenuFolder);
    }
    var startMenuLink = getShell().CreateShortcut(startMenuFolder + "\\Uninstall " + programDesc + ".lnk");
    startMenuLink.TargetPath = installedScript;
    startMenuLink.Arguments = "--uninstall";
    startMenuLink.WindowStyle = 1;
    startMenuLink.IconLocation = "wscript.exe, 3";
    startMenuLink.Description = "Uninstall " + programDesc;
    startMenuLink.WorkingDirectory = installFolder;
    startMenuLink.Save();

    // Tell the user it was successful.
    getShell().Popup("The installation is complete.", 300, programDesc + " - Admin", 64);
}

/* void */
function uninstall() {
    // Uninstall Send To link.
    var sendToFolder = getShell().SpecialFolders("SendTo");
    var link = sendToFolder + "\\" + quickLaunchMenuItem + ".lnk";
    if (getFileSystem().FileExists(link)) {
        getFileSystem().DeleteFile(link);
    }

    // Uninstall file and folder in Program Files.
    if (getFileSystem().FileExists(installedScript)) {
        getFileSystem().DeleteFile(installedScript);
    }
    if (getFileSystem().FolderExists(installFolder)) {
        getShell().CurrentDirectory = "C:\\";  // Move away so we can delete it.
        getFileSystem().DeleteFolder(installFolder);
    }

    // Uninstall Start Menu link and folder.
    var programsFolder = getShell().SpecialFolders("Programs");
    var startMenuFolder = programsFolder + "\\" + programDesc;
    var startMenuLink = startMenuFolder + "\\Uninstall " + programDesc + ".lnk";
    if (getFileSystem().FileExists(startMenuLink)) {
        getFileSystem().DeleteFile(startMenuLink);
    }
    if (getFileSystem().FolderExists(startMenuFolder)) {
        getFileSystem().DeleteFolder(startMenuFolder);
    }

    getShell().Popup("It has been removed.", 300, programDesc + " - Admin", 64);
}

/* void */
function createQuickLaunchLinkFor(targetName) {
    var target = getFileSystem().GetFile(targetName);
    var link = getShell().CreateShortcut(buildShortcutFileName(target));
    link.TargetPath = target.Path;
    link.WindowStyle = 1;
    link.Description = "Shortcut to " + target.Path;
    link.WorkingDirectory = target.ParentFolder;
    link.Save();
    getShell().Popup("A shortcut to " + targetName + " was added to the Quick Launch menu.", 300, programDesc, 64);
}

/* String */
function buildShortcutFileName(/* File */ target) {
    var homeDir = getEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
    var quickLaunchDir = homeDir + "\\Desktop";
    var name = quickLaunchDir + "\\" + target.Name;
    var duplicateFileStartIndex = 2;
    var i = duplicateFileStartIndex;
    
    // Check for extensions that should be removed.
    if (target.Type == "Application") {
        // Remove the extension.
        name = name.replace(/\.exe$/i, "");
    }
    else if (target.Type == "MS-DOS Batch File") {
        // Remove the extension.
        name = name.replace(/\.bat$/i, "");
    }
    
    // If the target is a Shortcut already, then do not append an additional
    // link extension to the new Shortcut name. Else...
    if (target.Type != "Shortcut") {
        // The new Shortcut name does not have a ".lnk" Shortcut extension
        // because the target didn't have one, so it needs one now.
        name += ".lnk";
    }
    
    // Resolve Shortcut name conflicts.
    while (getFileSystem().FileExists(name)) {
        if (i == duplicateFileStartIndex) {
            name = name.replace(/\.lnk$/i, "(" + i + ").lnk");
        }
        else {
            name = name.replace(/\(\d+\)\.lnk$/i, "(" + i + ").lnk");
        }
        i++; // Increment index and try again.
    }
    return name;
}

/* Boolean */
function isUninstallSwitch(arg) {
    var switches = new Array("--remove", "-remove", "--uninstall", "-uninstall");
    var i;
    for (i in switches) {
        if (arg == switches[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Main Program
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var targetName;

if (WScript.Arguments.length == 0) {
    // If there is no argument, then perform an install or remove.
    var op = askOperation();
    if (op == 'install') {
        install();
    }
    else if (op == 'remove') {
        uninstall();
    }
}
else {
    // There is at least one command line argument.
    targetName = WScript.Arguments(0);

    if (isUninstallSwitch(targetName)) {
        uninstall();
    }
    else {
        // If we have an argument then we were invoked from the SendTo menu,
        // so create a Quick Launch link for the given argument.
        createQuickLaunchLinkFor(targetName);
    }
}


Welcome to SuperUser. While we're glad you've shared your code with us, code itself is not a question.         Did you perhaps just find this code somewhere online and want to modify how it behaves?         Please spend a bit of time explaining the overall purpose of this code, what it is supposed to do, what it does do, and what you want it to do. Also, note that there is a sister site dedicated to programming questions, and a question entirely about programming may be better suited there, but only if it contains more/better information.

I am aware that I've edited to "send shortcuts to Desktop".
My purpose is:
1.to make it working with files and folders.
2.avoid the popup window
3. add this to the main context menu directly instead of clicking "Send to" then "Desktop (create shortcut)"
I've managed to add this to Registry like this:
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Add To Desktop\command]
@="wscript.exe "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Add To Desktop\Add To Desktop.js" "%1""
And it works perfectly with files but not with folders.
I hope I have explained myself clearly.
THANKS!

In case you want to know,this is taken from :
https://sourceforge.net/projects/sendtoquicklaun/files/

The posted code incudes install and remove routines that are not needed, was originally written for creating shortcuts in the QuickLaunch folder, and does not handle creating shortcuts to folders. Starting from that code is adding unnecessary complication to a simple requirement.
To replicate the functionality of Send to > Desktop (create shortcut) at the root of the context menu, all you need is a context menu registry entry for AllFileSystemObjects and a simple script to create the shortcut.
The script could be written in PowerShell, but then there would be a brief console flash unless the script is called by VBScript or JScript, so it makes sense to write it directly in one of those two languages. Since VBScript will become an uninstalled Feature On Demand in 2027, JScript is a better choice.
Change the reg file to match the location where you save the script.
CreateDesktopShortcutJS.reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\AllFileSystemObjects\shell\Create shortcut on Desktop\command]
@="WScript C:\\Tools\\CreateDesktopShortcut.js \"%1\""

CreateDesktopShortcut.js
if (WScript.Arguments.length == 0) WScript.Quit();
targetPath = WScript.Arguments(0);
includeExtension = true;
oWSH = WScript.CreateObject('WScript.Shell');
oFSO = WScript.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
baseName = oFSO.GetBaseName(targetPath);
if (includeExtension) baseName = oFSO.GetFileName(targetPath);
basePath = oWSH.SpecialFolders('Desktop') + '\\' + baseName;
shortcutPath = basePath + '.lnk';
count = 2;
while (oFSO.FileExists(shortcutPath)) {
    shortcutPath = basePath + ' (' + count + ')' + '.lnk';
    count++;
}
shortcut = oWSH.CreateShortcut(shortcutPath);
shortcut.TargetPath = targetPath;
shortcut.Save();

As requested, here's a PowerShell version. This is slower to launch than JScript and will flash a PowerShell window, so it's an inferior solution.
CreateDesktopShortcutPS.reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\AllFileSystemObjects\shell\Create shortcut on Desktop\command]
@="PowerShell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Window Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\\Tools\\CreateDesktopShortcut.ps1 \"%1\""

CreateDesktopShortcut.ps1
param ($targetPath)
if ($targetPath -eq $null) {Exit}
$includeExtension = $true
$oWSH = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$baseName = (Get-Item $targetPath).Basename
if ($includeExtension) {$baseName = (Get-Item $targetPath).Name}
$basePath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop') + '\' + $baseName
$shortcutPath = $basePath + '.lnk'
$count = 2
while (Test-Path $shortcutPath) {
    $shortcutPath = "$basePath($count).lnk"
    $count++
}
$shortcut = $oWSH.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath)
$shortcut.targetPath = $targetPath
$shortcut.Save()

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to convert the PowerShell code above to a one-liner so that no external file is needed, but be warned that, just like Microsoft's Open PowerShell window here command, a one-liner will be tripped up by a folder or file name with an apostrophe, such as Bob's Files. Workarounds using the registry or a temp file to pass %1 are possible but complicated.

You deserve 5 stars.I know this is too much to ask ,but could you please edit the following .ps script to make it working as the .js
$WSHShell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$Target     = Get-Item -Path $Args[0]
$LinkPath = '{1}{0}.lnk' -f $Target.Name, $WSHShell.SpecialFolders['Desktop']
$Shortcut = $WSHShell.CreateShortcut($LinkPath)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $Target.FullName
$Shortcut.Save()

How to could you edit the (CreateDesktopShortcut.js) to append a file extension to the shortcut ? THANKS.

Done. There's now an includeExtension variable. I've also cleaned up the code to make the JScript and PowerShell examples as similar as possible.

Much obliged! and thank you!
